# Flutter Inhertied widgets in a widget (stateless of statefull)

Tags: flutter, inherited-widget, statelesswidget

in Flutter we access an inherited widget fields by using its static `of` method:

```
Inhertied_widget.of(context).wanted_field
```

so, my question is, in a widget (stateless or statefull) when we use something like this:

```
final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

or:

```
MediaQueryData media = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

does this mean that the widget inherits from `MediaQuery` or `ModalRoute`

thank you.

Comment: Look at the *Inherited* section in this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Comment: it shows that MediaQuery inherits from Widget, class wise. which doesn't make sense in this case because we are calling MediaQuery of method in a Widget. does InhertiedWidget mean that MediaQuery is a Widget's parent in the Widget tree ?